# preg_replace_callback gives multiple errors

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I get an error on this line:

```
return preg_replace_callback("/([\\xF-\xC\xF]{1,1}[\\xBF-\\xBF]+)/e", _utf8_to_html("\\")', $data);
```

> [cgi:error] [pid 8213] [client 151.56.154.134:58848] AH01215: PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '_utf8_to_html("\1")', to be a valid callback in /home/informag/public_html/filename.php on line 951: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/ea-php54

Any idea to debug it?

Comment: **1.** There seem to be a rough `'` after the second argument. **2.** You say that you get multiple errors but you've only posted one.
 **3.** As the message says, the second argument need to be a valid [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) callback, not a function call. Please [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for some examples on how to use it properly.

Comment: post your `$data`  and expected output first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

besides the fact that there is a typo in the line (extra `'` at the end of the second parameter) php actually expects the "callback" parameter to be either an anonymous function or string containing the name of the function to call. In your case, it would look something like:

```
function _utf8_to_html() {
    // some logic...
}

preg_replace_callback("/([\\xF-\xC\xF]{1,1}[\\xBF-\\xBF]+)/e", '_utf8_to_html', $data);
```

or

```
$replacement = "\\"
preg_replace_callback("/([\\xF-\xC\xF]{1,1}[\\xBF-\\xBF]+)/e", function() use ($replacement) {
    //some logic...
}, $data);
```

note that only the anonymous function solution will allow you to use more than one parameter in your callback function.